# Vue3 - imported module is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, vuejs3

Update: After downgrading vue-cli to 4.5.19 code is working fine.. So I think it's issue related with vue-cli or its dependency.

I've created simple vue.js project using vue-cli. After adding to the project package [timecode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/timecode) by `npm install timecode --save` and try to use it in Vue component, imported module is undefined. I've a feeling this is problem related with webpack. Timecode package is written in commonJS and when I use it outside this project, it works fine. Any ideas?

@vue/cli v5.0.8,
npm v8.11.0,
node v16.16.0

package.json

```
{
  "name": "hello-world",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "timecode": "^0.0.4",
    "vue": "^3.2.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0"
  }
}
```

vue.config.js

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true
})
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ]
}
```

main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <HelloWorld />
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

HelloWorld.vue

```
<template></template>

<script setup>
import timecode from "timecode";
console.log(timecode); // { }
const timeCode = timecode.Timecode; // undefinied
const tc = timeCode.init({ framerate: "29.97", timecode: "01:00:00:00" }); // Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'init')
tc.add(4);
tc.add("00:02:03:00");

console.log(tc.toString());
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

[Output in console](https://www.npmjs.com/package/timecode)

```
app.js:167 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'init')
at setup (HelloWorld.vue?e90b:7:1)
at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:155:1)
at setupStatefulComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:7186:1)
at setupComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:7140:1)
at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5493:1)
at processComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5468:1)
at patch (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5058:1)
at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5607:1)
at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:185:1)
at instance.update (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5714:1)
```

When I use this package, without vue, by simple `npm init`, `npm install timecode --save` and call it form node `node index.js` I don't have this problems.

index.js

```
const timecode = require("timecode").Timecode; // all fine
const tc = timecode.init({ framerate: "29.97", timecode: "01:00:00:00" });
tc.add(4)
tc.add("00:02:03:00");
tc.toString();
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "timecode": "^0.0.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Vue 3 Composite API you can register the package locally and use it

```
<template>
   
</template>

<script setup>
import timecode from 'timecode'
//create the constant value and assign it with the imported timecode
const timeCode = timecode.Timecode;
const tc = timeCode.init({ framerate: "29.97", timecode: "01:00:00:00" });
tc.add(4);
tc.add("00:02:03:00");

console.log(tc.toString());
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

If you are using Vue 3 Optional API you can try like this.

```
<template>

</template>

<script>
import timecode from 'timecode'

export default {
    data: () => ({
        timeCode: timecode.Timecode
    }),

    methods: {
        //create a function to use your time code

        useMyTimeCode() {

            let tc = this.timeCode.init({ framerate: "29.97", timecode: "01:00:00:00" });
            tc.add(4);
            tc.add("00:02:03:00");
            console.log(tc.toString());
        }
    },

    created() {

        //you can use you function anywhere and you can even modify the function to pass parameters
        this.useMyTimeCode();
    }
}


</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Remember to install the package as

> npm i timecode

Comment: I've tried with composition api and 'old style', and still got the same err:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'init') at setup (HelloWorld.vue?e90b:7:1). 
Module is ofc installed. When I log it to the console, I got empty object.

Comment: Can you share the codes for either of the two (Composition or Optional)?

Comment: I also see that I got this module in my node_modules, so I don't understand. I've used exactly your code. This is a defaut project generated by vue-cli so I don't have any more code there.

Comment: Sorry I did not get you well. What module?

Comment: That installed by npm - timecode :).

Comment: Can you share the Composition API codes that you created so that I can check if there is any issue?

Comment: Ok. I've shared it in my question.

Comment: Ok, I downgraded version of vue-cli from 5.0.8 to 4.5.19, setuped new project and code is now working fine... So I think, it's some issue related with vue-cli.

Comment: Thats sound great

Comment: I'd rather know why this module doesn't work with the latest vue-cli (5.0.8) or how to configure it to work. I haven't found any open ticket on theirs github.